# Make controller property persistent

Tags: ember.js

What is the best way to remember the property value of a controller? Take a look here:

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/osoFiZi/1/edit?html,js,output)

I want to remember if an element was expanded, but only during the current session, I don't want to save this value into the datastore. The problem is, doing the following steps:

- Expand "Artist"
- Expand "Album"
- Collapse "Artist"
- Expand again "Artist"

"Album" is also collapsed! The value `isExpanded` from the "Album" was lost, seems that ember recreates the controller every time. Which would we a good solution to remember the value of `isExpanded`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add property to model

```
App.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
  isExpanded: false, // this property will not be included into PUT request when you will save record
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  albums: DS.hasMany('album', {async: true})
});
```

and toggle it in controller

```
actions: {
  toggleExpanded: function() {
    this.toggleProperty('model.isExpanded');
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/OtEBoNO/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to be persisted past the lifetime of the controller then you need to save it in a controller that will stay in scope as long as you want it to live (I'm not sure what your full intent is, but if it's really a lifetime of the page value you may want to store it on the application controller)

http://jsbin.com/osoFiZi/5/edit

```
App.AlbumController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['artist'],
  actions: {
    toggleExpanded: function() {              
      this.toggleProperty('controllers.artist.isAlbumsExpanded');              
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I moved the `isExpanded` property to the model, as Anton suggests. Ember documentation recommends, as you say, save the property in the controller, and I would prefer put it in the controller, but if I create multiple artists with multiple albums, the code to maintain the property value becomes too complicated.